# iOS Azure Mobile Service Completion Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure

i try to get some data from Azure, all works fine.
My problem is to populate the Data in a table view.

Here is my Implementaion of the TableViewController (only the important):

```
@interface tableview ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) AzureService *ClientService;

@end

@implementation overview

@synthesize tableViewObject,tabledata,ClientService;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableViewObject setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableViewObject setDataSource:self];    

    self.ClientService = [[AzureService alloc]init];

    [self.ClientService DatamyWay:^
    {
        [self.tableViewObject reloadData];
        NSLog(@"Reload Table after complete Request");
    }];


}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.ClientService.loadedItems count];
}

@end
```

Here´s the Implementation of the method form the Service

```
- (void) DatamyWay:(completionBlock)completion
{
    [self.table readWithCompletion:^(MSQueryResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if(error) { // error is nil if no error occured
            NSLog(@"ERROR %@", error);
        } else {

            [self.loadedItems addObjectsFromArray:result.items];

            for(NSDictionary *item in result.items) { // items is NSArray of records that match query
                NSLog(@"Location Name: %@", [item objectForKey:@"name"]);
            }


        }
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        completion();
    });
}
```

Here the debugger output

```
    2015-06-17 22:24:02.848 type2[3041:301640] Reload Table after complete Request
2015-06-17 22:24:03.601 type2[3041:301640] Location Name: abc
2015-06-17 22:24:03.601 type2[3041:301640] Location Name: def
2015-06-17 22:24:03.602 type2[3041:301640] Location Name: ghj
2015-06-17 22:24:03.602 type2[3041:301640] Location Name: klm
```

so i´ve leraned the call is asynchron. i want to check when the Completion code is called. So i decided to write the "Reload" NS Log Message. As you can see in the Debugger output, the NSlog message from the Completion block writes before the NSlog message in the Service Method. so the numbersinRowSection can´t count and nothing will happen. I hope the problem is described clearly.

Regards

Comment: i think i should use appdelegate methods to set the same property. i try this tomorrow.

Comment: doesent work to save the result in appdelegate an catch this in completion block.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know, i shouldn´t post my own answer. I hope someone can help this one.

Put the Completion block in the Request.
code that works in my Service Implementation

```
    - (void) DatamyWay:(completionBlock)completion
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [self.table readWithCompletion:^(MSQueryResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if(error) { // error is nil if no error occured
            NSLog(@"ERROR %@", error);
        } else {


            [delegate.loadedItems addObjectsFromArray:result.items];

            for(NSDictionary *item in result.items) { // items is NSArray of records that match query
                NSLog(@"Location Name: %@", [item objectForKey:@"name"]);
            }

            completion();


        }
    }];
}
```